# Combine Nested Array in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to combine and display the `validationMessages`. How do it combine since they are nested?

```js
const errors = [
    {
        "id": "101_1.jpeg",
        "imageValidationMessages": [
            {
                "attribute": "test",
                "validationMessages": [
                    "Error message 1"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]


  const errorMessages =
    errors?.length &&
    errors?.imageValidationMessages?.flatMap(
      (o) => o.validationMessages
    )
    
    
    console.log(errorMessages)
```

Comment: `validationMessages` is a property of objects in the `imageValidationMessages` array - you need to dig deeper

Comment: also, errors?.imageValidationMessages` will always be undefined, since `errors` is an array

Comment: @Bravo. Can you help me answer it?

Comment: you have two helpful answers 3 hours ago below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const errors = [
    {
        "id": "101_1.jpeg",
        "imageValidationMessages": [
            {
                "attribute": "test",
                "validationMessages": [
                    "Error message 1"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
let arr=errors.map(e=>e.imageValidationMessages.map(p=>p.validationMessages)).flat(2)
console.log(arr)
```

---

```js
const errors = [
    {
        "id": "101_1.jpeg",
        "imageValidationMessages": [
            {
                "attribute": "test",
                "validationMessages": [
                    "Error message 1"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
let arr=errors.flatMap(e=>e.imageValidationMessages.flatMap(p=>p.validationMessages))
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Is there a shorter way to do this?

Comment: @Joseph I update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
 const errorMessages =
 errors?.length &&
 errors?.flatMap((err => err.imageValidationMessages?.flatMap(
  (o) => o.validationMessages
 )))
```

Comment: Is there a shorter way to do this?